# Jesey Client on JBoss 7.1.1 throw java.net.SocketException: Protocol family unavailable for IPv6 address

Tags: java, jersey, jboss7.x, ipv6

I'm trying to connect using Jersey Client to a REST service.
When I'm using IPv4 address everything works fine.
When I'm trying to replace the server address with its IPv6 the following exception is thrown:

> com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException:
>   java.net.SocketException: Protocol family unavailable
>           at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler.handle(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:128)
>           at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:551)
>           at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:556)
>           at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$200(WebResource.java:69)
>           at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.put(WebResource.java:475)
>           at com.bmc.aps.agent.jersey.JerseyClient.put(JerseyClient.java:169)
>           at com.bmc.aps.agent.portal.PortalConnection.handshake(PortalConnection.java:304)
>           at com.bmc.aps.agent.portal.PortalConnection.run(PortalConnection.java:786)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636) Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Protocol family unavailable
>           at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
>           at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:310)
>           at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:176)
>           at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:163)
>           at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:537)
>           at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:487)
>           at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:174)
>           at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:409)
>           at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:530)
>           at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.(HttpClient.java:240)
>           at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:321)
>           at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:338)
>           at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:806)
>           at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:747)
>           at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:672)
>           at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:850)
>           at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler$1$1.getOutputStream(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:200)
>           at com.sun.jersey.api.client.CommittingOutputStream.commitWrite(CommittingOutputStream.java:114)
>           at com.sun.jersey.api.client.CommittingOutputStream.write(CommittingOutputStream.java:86)
>           at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(StreamEncoder.java:220)
>           at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlushBuffer(StreamEncoder.java:290)
>           at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:294)
>           at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:140)
>           at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:229)
>           at java.io.BufferedWriter.flush(BufferedWriter.java:253)
>           at com.sun.jersey.core.util.ReaderWriter.writeToAsString(ReaderWriter.java:178)
>           at com.sun.jersey.core.provider.AbstractMessageReaderWriterProvider.writeToAsString(AbstractMessageReaderWriterProvider.java:125)
>           at com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StringProvider.writeTo(StringProvider.java:85)
>           at com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StringProvider.writeTo(StringProvider.java:57)
>           at com.sun.jersey.api.client.TerminatingClientHandler.writeRequestEntity(TerminatingClientHandler.java:291)
>           at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler._invoke(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:179)
>           at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler.handle(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:126)
>           ... 8 more

I tried running with `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=false` and `-Djava.net.preferIPv6Stack=true` but it didn't help.

The same code with IPv6 works on the same machine on Weblogic.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem indeed resolves by setting `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=false`, but passing it as an argument to `./standalone.sh` is not enough as this value is rewritten in `standalone.conf` and `standalone.sh`.

Therefor, what should be done is searching for `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true` inside both files and modifying them to `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=false`.

Answer (score 0):

Start JBoss in this way

> JBoss 7 : ./standalone.sh -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=false

or

> JBoss 7 : ./standalone.sh -Djava.net.preferIPv6Stack=true

By default IPv4 is enabled in Java, you need to tell explicitly to use Ipv6

Comment: which JDK/JRE are you using?

Comment: Sun Microsystems Inc., 'OpenJDK Server VM', 1.6.0

Comment: BTW, the same code works with Weblogic using JRockit_160_14_R27.6.5-32

Comment: You should have Oracle JDK 7 or above. JDK 6 have some issues in some environments. just try with that

Comment: I was able to resolve this. Look at my answer. Thanks for you help!